# SignalR JavaScript client error in connect to remote .Net Core Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm using Asp.Net Core (3) SignalR (Latest Version) as described in Microsoft's tutorial at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1 but having error in connect to hub.

**NuGet packages installed on server:**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR(1.1.0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core(1.1.0)
```

My server runs at http://localhost:52852 and the client is running at http://localhost:10843.

I have added the client URL as acceptable Origin in server CORS policy.

**Server Startup :**

```
// ConfigureServices
    services.AddCors(options => 
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:10843/")
                    .AllowCredentials();
                }));

    services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => {
        hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });

// App Configure

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapHub<AsteriskHub>("/signalr");
    });

// Hub
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        // Some Codes ...
    }
```

**Client Javascript :**

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:52852/signalr")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

connection.start();
```

I have read many documents similar to my issue over Microsoft and Asp.Net and Stackoverflow posts but confused why I have this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:52852/signalr/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:10843' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:10843/")`

Please remove trailing slash `/` from the end of your URL, like below.

```
.WithOrigins("http://localhost:10843")
```

Besides, please apply your CORS policy with `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")`, like below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //... other middleware ...

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseRouting();

    //...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapHub<AsteriskHub>("/signalr");
    });

    //...
}
```